# installing and using doctrine with zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, orm, doctrine

I have been using zend framework quite a long. Now I want to integrate doctrine orm framwork with zend. I don't know how to do that. Is there any setup guide with some basic examples? and How can I put it on shared host where i don't have console access?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's various resources around.

- Benjamin Eberlei's zf-doctrine (Zend 1 / Doctrine 1) Integration suite - https://github.com/beberlei/zf-doctrine
- I also just got this webinar announcement in the Zend newsletter (requires a free Zend account to view) - http://www.zend.com/webinar/Framework/70170000000bSrG-webinar-zf-v-1-doctrine-v-2-20101214.flv

Regarding deployment, you just build your project locally then upload the complete application to your host. Both Zend Framework and Doctrine are just libraries of PHP files.